# Losing Session on POST

Tags: java, session, servlets, session-variables

I have been trying to find the reason as to why my session would be lost when I do a POST.

I am checking my session all throughout my app but the session will drop when I call a particular servlet and it only drops on this particular one. The issue is intermittent so it is very frustrating. I'm not sure what is needed so I'll put as much info as I can up.

The page is accessed through a servlet. I can verify that the session is still the same.

As the user is routing through the app, I can see that the session is still the same.

Checking Session:HTTP Session CEHKIIMEKHMH
Calling Get Details
Checking Session:HTTP Session CEHKIIMEKHMH
Calling Project Details
Checking Session:HTTP Session CEHKIIMEKHMH
Calling Attachment Controller
Checking Session:HTTP Session CEHKIIMEKHMH

```js
public class Attachments extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
 
  System.out.println("Calling Attachment Controller");
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
  System.out.println("Checking Session:"+session);
  
  if(session != null){
   Object projectId = session.getAttribute("projectId");
   request.getRequestDispatcher(response.encodeURL("views/attachments.jsp")).forward(request, response);
  }else{
   System.err.println("Invalid session");
   response.sendRedirect("/");
  }
    
 }

}
```

Here is my form posting. The form is actually submitted via javascript after I perform validation, I just merely call $('#files).submit(); not sure if that really matters or not.

```html
<form id="files" name="files" method="POST" action="FileUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The moment they post, the session is lost

Calling File Upload
Checking Session:null
null

Here is the start of the servlet

```js
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  
  System.out.println("Calling File Upload");
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
  System.out.println("Checking Session:"+session);
  
  if(session != null){
   Object projectId = session.getAttribute("projectId");  
   System.out.println("Accessing File Upload: Session is valid");
```

It's the same method all across the board. I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: This may be due to multipart form request. Can you try another servlet doPost without multipart request and check if you still see session.

Comment: Is this problem occur at development or both(development&production)?

Comment: Currently this is only happening in development. I haven't moved it into production because of this issue. I will give your suggestion a try and see if it still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I've narrowed down the issue but I still have not resolved it yet. It happens during my redirect. I also was not encoding the URL correctly. I have modified all my redirects to have the folowing:

```js
   request.getRequestDispatcher(response.encodeRedirectURL("views/attachments.jsp")).forward(request, response);
```

This only resolves it on the server side though and does not provide a solution when I am handling redirects from the client.